# Interface of object parameter with default value and default property

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to declare interface of the parameter of a function, and the parameter is an object, if the parameter is not given, defult is `{}`, the interface is like this:

```
interface ReadCsvConfig {
    index_col: boolean | number[];
    delimiter: string;
    header: string[] | number;
    dataType: string;
}
```

and the function is like this:

```
function read_csv (filePath:string,{
    index_col=false,
    delimiter=',',
    header=0,
    dataType='number'
}={}){
...
}
```

and now, how to declare the second parameter to be `ReadCsvConfig`?

I tried to declare like this:

```
{
    index_col=false,
    delimiter=',',
    header=0,
    dataType='number'
}: ReadCsvConfig={}
```

but it comes the error: `index_col is missing in type {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are destructuring the second parameter, you can specify the type of any of the properties but you can't specify the type of the parameter you destructured because there's no binding for it (e.g. there's no variable that is actually a `ReadCsvConfig`). You can do a type cast on the `{}` expression for the default value with:

```
function read_csv (filePath:string,{
    index_col=false,
    delimiter=',',
    header=0,
    dataType='number'
}={} as ReadCsvConfig){
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . . .